# Iterate over all turtle variables

Tags: python, list, turtle-graphics

I've made a lot of turtles (14 actually) and I want to set all of them to hideturtle(), penup(), speed(0). I can put my turtle variables in a list and iterate over the list but is there a way to get Python to create the list by appending all the variables of Turtle class in the project?

I have tried getting a list of variables with `dir()` then using `isinstance(x, Turtle)` to filter out the ones belonging to Turtle class, but it seems `dir()` only returns strings of variable names, so can't be used to test for variable class.

Comment: Please provide more information on what you are trying to do, and your attempt at solving

Comment: No there is not — you'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, martineau.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to get Python to create the list by appending all the
>   variables of Turtle class in the project?

Contrary to the comments, yes there is.  It's the `turtles()` method of the singular screen instance:

```
>>> from turtle import Screen, Turtle
>>> screen = Screen()
>>> help(screen.turtles)

Help on method turtles in module turtle:

turtles() method of turtle.Screen() instance
    Return the list of turtles on the screen.

    Example (for a TurtleScreen instance named screen):
    >>> screen.turtles()
    [<turtle.Turtle object at 0x00E11FB0>]
(END)
```

Here are some examples from StackOverflow that use this method:

- [... making a traffic light with Python turtle
  ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48069888/5771269)
- [Set the maxiumum distance that a turtle can
  go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58331483/5771269)
- [How to initialize multiple turtles in Python with
  classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58786015/5771269)

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks very much. That completely provides what I needed.